# three20 How do I show a Disclosure Button when i use didSelectObject on TTTableSubtitleItem

Tags: iphone, three20

I use TTTableSubtitleItem to crete the cells for a table. I then use didSelectObject to sent an object to the detail view controller. To prevent the message being sent twice I have to set the TTTableSubtitleItem URL to nil. Because of this the Disclosure Button will not display?

```
    [TTTableSubtitleItem itemWithText:[chunks objectAtIndex: 0] 
                                 subtitle:@"Link To Website"
                                 imageURL:@""
                             defaultImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.png"]
                                      URL:nil 
                             accessoryURL:@"http://www.google.com"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue and the way I got around it was by subclassing the item cell (so for you it'd be `TTTableSubtitleItemCell` and overriding the `setObject` method to manually include the disclosure button as follow:

```
- (void)setObject:(id)object {
if (_item != object) {
  [_item release];
  _item = [object retain];

  [super setObject:object];

  self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
```

I also used this method to allow myself to have the selection style still be blue even though I wasn't handling the URL in the expected way.  This would happen by also just adding

```
  self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
```

right after the other call.

Note you'll also need to add the mapping between the items you care about and this new custom item cell in your data source. This requires overriding one method in a custom data source. If you want all of your `TTTableSubtitleItem`s to have the disclosure button, you can map `TTTableSubtitleItem` to your new custom item cell. Otherwise just create a custom subclass of `TTTableSubtitleItem` as well that doesn't make any changes to it. Assuming your two new subclasses are `CustomItem` and `CustomItemCell` your data source would override the following method to look like so:

```
- (Class)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellClassForObject:(id)object {
  if ([object isKindOfClass:[CustomItem class]]) {
    return [CustomItemCell class];
  } else {
    return [super tableView:tableView cellClassForObject:object];
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your help with this. When I create the subclass do I have to create a datasource file to apply the cell to the table rows? at the moment i just use [dataSource.items addObject:[TTTableSubtitleItem it....

Comment: Yep, I'll edit my response so I can use code markup to make it clearer

Comment: Wow great answer, thanks for taking the time to help me with this Andrew. I now have it working correctly using your answer.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have a simpler issue where I'm trying to get my selectionStyle works: http://bit.ly/jZCguM. It get highlighted but somehow the bluecolour background doesn't disappear. It just stuck there.